# getting values from sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the value from sessionStorage and map it to my ng-model, but 
when i do that in my ng-init its not working.

The problem is in my actual code i am inside a ng-repeat so my sessionStorage becomes like below:

```
sessionStorage.getItem(item.itemId)
```

HTMl Code:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

      Not Working <input ng-init = 'name = sessionStorage.getItem("SavedString")'  type="text" ng-model="name" >

      Working <input type="text" ng-model="name1" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  sessionStorage.setItem("SavedString","I'm a value saved with SessionStorage");

    //RETRIEVE VALUE
    $scope.name = "test"
    $scope.name1 = sessionStorage.getItem("SavedString");


    $scope.hi = 'Hello World';
}
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/393revrn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i too tried  in your way but i didn't find a the requirements to achieve this ......so i tried with making a function call with in init and appended session data to that model then i can see the proper output by making `ng-init ='some()'` [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BJGOM98n8bMNPTMWEAKj?p=preview)  is the working plunker

**UPDATE**

From some source i found that  HTML cannot understand session variables directly.

Answer (score 1):

The `sessionStorage`, when accessed from the `ng-init` directive, is not understood by Angular; it will be parsed and interpreted as if it were a **$scope function** (which, I assume, is not).

So, in order for your example to work, you should do something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
```